# Angular 2 call Observable on component Initialize

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to call observable on component load. In Below function. I have monthly() in service in which i am sending data using subject next(). I want to send data from load component to receive component. current when i hit toggle-button using (change) event data is sen correctly to receive function but i want to send data on load component Initialize. I tried calling function ngOnInit() but its not working for me.

Please help how do i trigger toggleFunc() when load component id initialize so that i get correct data in this.service.monthData$.subscribe in receive component.

I tried refering similar questions but nothing worked for me.

```js
// load component

ngOnInit(){
  if(yr > 0){
    this.monthData = false;
  } else {
    this.monthData = true;
  }
  this.toggleFunc(this.monthData);
}

toggleFunc(val){
  this.service.monthly(val);
}

// service

public monthData = new subject();
public monthData$ = this.monthData.asObservable();

monthly(val){
  this.monthData.next(val);
}

//receive component

ngOnInit(){
  this.service.monthData$.subscribe(val =>
  console.log(val);
  );
}
```

```html
<!-- Load Component -->

<toggle-button [(ngModel)]="monthly" (change)="toggleFunc($event)"></toggle-button>
```

Comment: can you please help me how do i call it on component load

Comment: @user184994 Of course, it will trigger. asObservable would be useless otherwise.

Comment: There are 2 ngOnInit methods. Do they belong to same component? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: one is for load component and other for receive component

Comment: The question doesn't reflect their relationship. It should contain all relevant code in order to get proper answer. A plunk would also help.

Comment: If the subscribe in the receive component is executed after the toggleFunc execution in the load component, no data will be received. Instead of using Subject, you can try ReplaySubject.